# Как автоматически заранее заполнить форму django?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть форма

```py
class FileFieldForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = FileFeedbackEventToSubscriber
        fields = ('FeedbackFile', 'event', 'subscriber')
```

Модель:

```py
class FileFeedbackEventToSubscriber(Model):
    event = models.ManyToManyField(FileFeedbackEvent, verbose_name='Событие')
    subscriber = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name='Подписчик')
    FeedbackFile = models.FileField(upload_to='files/', null=True, blank=True)
    SubscriptionDate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

Выдает вот так:

[image: 1]

Поле SubscriptionDate всегда заполняется, это понятно, мне нужно сделать, чтоб остальные поля, кроме FeedbackFile заполнялись автоматически. Все данные для этого передаются. Как это можно сделать так, чтоб при входе в форму даже не предлагало ввести данные в эти поля формы?

Answer (score 2):

Словарь `initial`. Вы его можете передать во View-класс, наследующий от `FormView` или `CreateView`. Примерно так:

```
class CreatePost(FormView):
    form_class = ...
    template_name = ...
    initial = {'title':'заголовок'}
```

В `initial` первое вы указываете имя вашего поля, второе его значение.

Или можете отдельно в `forms.py` для полей прописать `initial`. Ну к примеру:

```
Class CreateForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(initial='value field title')
```

Еще можно указать у полей (в модели) `default`, но лучше это сделать на уровне формы, а не модели.

---

Так же `initial` можно передать в форму при ее создании, или переопределить в `__init__` методе формы для конкретного поля

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['field'].initial = ....
```